# XPATH - how to start parsing only at a numerical character

Tags: xpath

I want to ignore any characters up until a numeric one as I am trying to grab a date from html webpages. Example code:

```
<div id="example">example text 4 December 2013</div>
```

So I want to only grab the date "4 December 2013" and ignore the first bit of text "example text ", so effectively start parsing when a number is spotted.

The length of text and words at the start of this string are unknown and can differ in size, the date will always be in this format and at the end of the tag.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

With Xpath, you can divide the data among two tags, like
example text
4 December 2013

Now, you can fetch the numeric data with Xpath expression, "//NumericData".

Else, just pick the whole data and then parse it using simple string manipulation classes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback but I don't quite understand what you mean, could you perhaps provide an example? Thanks.

Comment: `<AlphaData>example</AlphaData>` `<NumericData>4 December 2013<NumericData>`. Now you can easily apply xpath expression on  "//NumericData". Also, you can write code that will read the data from your tag (example text 4 December), parse it and create new tags (i.e. AlphaData and Numericdata at run time). Once you have these tags you can easily read the Numeric Data from your XML file. This is the work around I can think of.

Comment: Also, if you are using Xpath 2.0, you can use `/div/text()[substring-after(. , 'example text')]` to get the desired results.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate you letting me know I can do it but how do I do it?! cannot see any information on the internet for this "//NumericData" expression. Also the substring information does not do what I want it to, this parses after the text I specify, I do not know what that text will be.